# Updating News on a CMS

Tags: php, mysql

so I've been trying to write a CMS for a client to update their website. I'm working on trying to get the update news script to work, and I was wondering how I could get the script to not only update the news itself but also the title. Here is the script:

PHP:

```
    //used to get data from previous page. $previous_title was so I can use it to set the where in the update query.
    if($_GET['title']) {
            $title = $_GET['title'];
             $previous_title = $_GET['title'];
    }
    if($_POST['title']) {
            $title = $_POST['title'];
            $news = $_POST['news'];

            //used to update both news and title
           mysql_query("UPDATE `News` SET `Title`='$title', `Content`='$news' WHERE `Title`='$previous_title'");
    header("Location: viewNews.php");
    }
```

HTML:

```
                <form id = "addNews" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="hidden" id="hidden" value="hidden" />
                <input type="text" name="title" size="68" id = "title" value="<?php echo $query['Title'];?>"/><br/><br/>
                <textarea name="news" id="news"><?php echo $query['Content'];?></textarea><br />
                <input type="submit" value="Update News"/>
                </form>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In update query you are updating both of fields `Title &  Content`

```
UPDATE `News` SET `Title`='$title', `Content`='$news' WHERE `Title`='$previous_title
```

But if you want to update only news then your SQL like this :

```
UPDATE `News` SET `Content`='$news' WHERE `Title`='$previous_title
```

You should take care of `$previous_title`
Because in this context `$previous_title` may not available

```
if($_POST['title']) {
            $title = $_POST['title'];
            $news = $_POST['news'];

           mysql_query("UPDATE `News` SET `Title`='$title', `Content`='$news' WHERE `Title`='$previous_title'");
    header("Location: viewNews.php");
    }
```

Comment: would there be any way as to update both the title and news then?